# Getting Attribute Error when running simple API example

Tags: python, api, attributes

I'm running a very simple API example:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
     def init(self):
         EClient.init(self, self)

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
app.run()
```

The Error I´m getting is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\Python projects\IB TWS\test_app.py", line
>   9, in 
>       app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)   File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\Python projects\IB TWS\ibapi\client.py",
>   line 151, in connect
>       self.decoder = decoder.Decoder(self.wrapper, self.serverVersion()) AttributeError: 'IBapi' object has no attribute 'wrapper'

If I check the code in the source file I see this (I've taken out some code that was not relevant):

```
class EClient(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        self.wrapper = wrapper

    def connect(self, host, port, clientId):
        self.decoder = decoder.Decoder(self.wrapper, self.serverVersion())
```

How is it possible that cannot find the wrapper attribute if it's on the `__init__` function of the class? What might I be missing?

Another question I have is, if the class `IBapi` takes 2 arguments (`EWrapper` and `EClient`) how is it possible that the object app is an instance of `IBapi` class with no parameters?

Just to clarify I've taken this example from the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Hiperfly, Your code seems faulty. Are you sure that you should have an `init()` method in you `IBapi` class? Is it possible that you don't want to define an `__init__()` instead.

Your class `IBapi` don't take 2 arguments the way you have defined it. Your code says that `IBapi` inherit  from classes `EWrapper` and `Eclient`. They are not "arguments" to your class. 

Are you sure about what you are doing?

Comment: same question in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61069169/11234834