# Interactive Broker Python API shows error: IB AttributeError: 'IBapi' object has no attribute 'connState'

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers, ib-api

I tried to make a simple Python program, that connects via the IB native API to my Demo Account. But when I run the program it comes an error: *IB AttributeError: 'IBapi' object has no attribute 'connState'*

The program looks like this:

```
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper  

class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
     def init(self):
         EClient.init(self, self) 

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)
app.run()
```

I used the tutorial from this website: https://algotrading101.com/learn/interactive-brokers-python-api-native-guide/

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The python initialization method that is automatically called after an object instance has been created is named `__init__`, not `init`.

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**init**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

In your code the `init` method will never be called. It should be:

```
from ibapi.client import EClient 
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper


class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):         
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

...
```

You might be interested in the Python API course in the [Traders' Academy](https://www.ibkr.com/en/index.php?f=45473&cat=none) on the IBKR website.